# mysqli_query syntax error with $_SESSION used

Tags: php

I had got the error like this

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

Here is my code (I used $_SESSION to get variable from the other page.)

```
$sql="insert into data(name,sex,time,suggest,eat,problem,student_suggest,tutor_suggest,other_suggest)   
values('$_SESSION['name']','$_SESSION['gender']','$_SESSION['time']','$_SESSION['suggest']','$_SESSION['eat']',  '$_SESSION['problem']','$_SESSION['student']','$_SESSION['tutor']','$_SESSION['other']')";

mysqli_query($cn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($cn));
```

Comment: Look into prepared statements, especially PDO.  This stops a lot of the potential problems you will have with all sorts of things, including names (or other fields) with quotes in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to proper write down variables.
It can't be :

`values('$_SESSION['name']',`

It has to be:

`values('".$_SESSION['name']."',`

Another good approach is to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data', $user, $pass);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO data (name, sex) VALUES (:name, :sex)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_SESSION['name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':sex', $_SESSION['gender']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You can improve this answer by adding prepared statements

Comment: Thanks! But I got error of PDO but your new way to proper write down is working. [ values('".$_SESSION['name']."', ]

Answer (score 1):

You are using single quote in worng sequnence and this generated  wrong code  ..

You could use string concat for avoid the  problem

but be carefulfor sqlijcection  using php var inside sql, (you should use PDO and param  binding.
Anyway related  to your question

```
      $sql="insert into data(name,sex,time,suggest,eat,problem,student_suggest,tutor_suggest,other_suggest)   
      values(" . $_SESSION['name'] . ","
      . $_SESSION['gender'] . ","
      . $_SESSION['time'] . ","
      . $_SESSION['suggest'] . ","
      . $_SESSION['eat']', . ","
      . $_SESSION['problem'] . ","
      . $_SESSION['student'] . ","
      . $_SESSION['tutor'] . ","
      . $_SESSION['other'] . ")";
```